# Менее стандартные ситуации с "ты" и "вы"

Tags: выбор-слов

Ситуации, когда мы обращаемся к человеку на "ты" и по имени или на "вы" и по имени-отчеству понятны и не требуют особых разъяснений. Формальное и неформальное общение.

А в каких ситуациях мы можем обратиться на "вы" и просто по имени или на "ты", а потом по имени-отчеству? Когда это будет уместно? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Будет вполне уместно "ты, Иван Васильич", если вы с Иван Васильичем знакомы сто лет и на дружеской ноге. Тогда можно Ваня, можно Иван, а можно Иван Васильич.

Наоборот тоже сколько угодно. "Вы, Иван" – так может, например, обращаться к молодому подчинённому его руководитель.

Comment: А если подчиненный того же возраста?

Comment: Ха. Это смотря какого. До тридцати – вполне. А если учесть прогрессирующую неформальность общения во всех сферах, то хоть до семидесяти. ))) А вообще, это не языковой вопрос, а этический.

Comment: Это словоупотребление в различных ситуациях. И его причины. А сами причины могут быть связаны с традициями, этикетом и т.д. и т.п. Но словоупотребление в любом случае - вопрос языковой.

Comment: "Ты, Иван" или "вы, Иван" – языковой вопрос?!

Comment: Словоупотребление "ты" и "вы" в различных ситуациях - бесспорно языковой вопрос. Как любой вопрос вариантов словоупотребления. Ну, а сам язык описывает принятые в обществе традиции и т.п. Не знаю, с чем вы собрались спорить..)